# Pegar somente um valor no resultado da consulta ao banco de dados

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Gostaria que ele passasse um `return` com apenas o numero de dados daquela tabela, porém ele esta retornando isso:

> ```
> C:\E. S>node dao.js
> Connected!
> [ RowDataPacket { 'COUNT(*)': 4 } ]
> ```

Código:

```
contaQuantidade(tabela){
        var conector = this.conectaBanco();
        conector.connect(function(err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("Connected!");          
            conector.query("select COUNT(*) from "+tabela, function (err, result) {
                if (err) throw err;
                var i = result;
            });
            conector.end();
        });
        return i;
    }
```

Como faço para pegar somente o numero `4`?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o [`AS`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) para criar um alias para `COUNT(*)`, para ficar mais fácil de acessar no JavaScript. Então a sua *query* ficará assim:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM nome_da_tabela;
```

O resultado virá assim:

```
+-------+
| count |
+-------+
|     4 |
+-------+
```

Em seguida, para acessar o valor, precisamos acessar o primeiro item do `RowDataPacket` retornado. Para isso, usaremos a seguinte notação:

```
// Acessa o primeiro elemento dos resultados:
//    ↓↓↓
result[0]
```

E para acessar o número retornado, basta acessar a propriedade `count`, conforme definimos como *alias* em nossa *query*.

```
result[0].count
```

O código fica mais ou menos assim:

```
connection.query('SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM ' + table + ';', (err, result) => {
  if (err) throw err

  // ℹ️ Acessamos o número de tabela na linha abaixo:
  const number = result[0].count

  console.log('Temos ' + number + ' registros na tabela ' + table + '.')
})
```